If you exceed the Personal Savings Allowance in the UK, do you personally have to report it to HMRC?
I'm based in the UK and am in full time employment. I pay tax at 20% via PAYE.
Due to increases in interest rates I've exceeded the £1000 PSA (Personal Savings Allowance) on interest earned across several savings accounts I have. Note: I am aware of using my ISA allowance to avoid this, but have used the full £20k allowance for the last 3 tax years, so this isn't an option.
I am being given conflicting information as to which of these 2 options applies:

I need to declare the interest earned to HMRC.
HMRC are automatically given this information via banks and adjust my tax code accordingly.

I have always believed it's option (2) and this is stated in various bank/building society websites. For example Skipton Building Society says

What happens if I exceed my Personal Savings Allowance?
If you’re employed or get a pension and the interest you earn exceeds your PSA, HMRC will automatically collect the tax you owe through your pay-as-you-earn (PAYE) tax code.

Similarly Lloyds Bank says

Banks and other financial institutions report all interest to HM Revenue & Customs (HMRC) at the end of each tax year.
If you’re employed, or you receive a pension, HMRC may simply change your tax code, so interest is taxed automatically.

The reason I asked this question is I spoke to NS&I about a savings bond I have and they suggested that NS&I do not handle this and that I should report it myself.
I suggested to the person on the phone I didn't believe this to be true, because it would mean people could avoid paying tax by simply not reporting it. In other words my understanding is the same as the quotes above - the banks/financial institutions report all figures to HMRC who then in turn automatically adjust tax codes to collect it.
Can anyone advise what is actually the case?
I have used the feature on GOV.uk to see whether I need to complete a self assessment tax return and the response was that I do not.

If the Self Assessment checker on the HMRC webpage says you don't need to submit a Self Assessment tax return, then you do not need to - and there's no other way to inform them of interest earned.
If you were filling in a Self Assessment anyway for other reasons, then you would of course have to declare the interest in there.
But in your situation, they will as you say be informed by the bank and will then adjust your tax code and collect the tax that way.(I once got a very alarming tax code adjustment when I briefly had the proceeds of a house sale in my bank account, so it doesn't take them long to notice!)

Re "there's no other way to inform them of interest earned". The person at NS&I who I spoke to suggested opening a  Personal Tax Account (https://www.gov.uk/personal-tax-account). I didn't go ahead with that on the basis I felt there's no need if HMRC are automatically given the figures, and it's not something I'd ever been advised to do by anyone else before.

The personal tax account still wouldn't let you inform them of interest earned without doing a Self Assessment. It would let you see how they've changed your tax code, but you should get a coding notice in the post for that anyway.
